# How to backup timeshift snapshots to S3

Tags: aws-cli, timeshift

I used Timeshift to create snapshots backups for my Ubuntu system, and it runs automatically every day. My goal is to store the backups in S3. Since I couldn't find a direct method to specify S3 as the backup destination in Timeshift, I used **`s3 sync`** to synchronize the backups from the default location **`/timeshift/snapshots`** to S3. The size of **`/timeshift/snapshots`** is only 7GB, but after uploading it to S3, it occupies 100GB. Why is that? And how can I resolve it?

I tried s3 cp，but the same.